# using Joins rather than sub queries in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, join

Hello Guys I am having following tables relationship  with me,

[image]

and I am writing following Nested Query in my Stored Procedure

```
. Select useremail,fullname,city,[state], allowAlerts,allowLetters,aboutMe,avatar,dateregistered,
          (Select COUNT(*) from blog_info where blog_info.userId = @userId)as blogCount,
           (Select count(*) from blog_info where blog_info.isfeatured = 1 AND blog_info.userId = @userId)as featuredCount,
           (Select COUNT(*) from blog_comments where blog_comments.userId = @userId)as commentsCount,
            (Select COUNT(*) from forum where forum.createdby = @userId) as forumCount,
             (Select COUNT(*) from forumresponse where forumresponse.userId = @userId)as responseCount 

          from user_info where _id = @userId.
```

i want to replace this nested Query with the Query that ues Joins .

Pleaes Help me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you want to convert to joins?

Comment: beacuse of performance Issues. As Joins are more performance oriented as compared to sub Queries.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the nested queries with joins? Do you hope to get a more efficient query? I doubt that it will help. Joins on the user id don't seem to really fit here.

Comment: You should probably look at making sure you have the right indexes. I can't see `JOINs` helping here. All the sub queries are non correlated and just return a scalar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    u.useremail,
    u.fullname,
    u.city,
    u.[state],
    u.allowAlerts,
    u.allowLetters,
    u.aboutMe,
    u.avatar,
    u.dateregistered,
    isnull(ub.blogCount,0) blogCount,
    uf.featuredCount,
    uf2.forumCount,
    ur.responseCount 
from
    user_info u
left outer join 
    (select userid, count(*) blogCount from blog_info group by userid) ub on ub.userid = u._id
```

**(and so on doing a similar join for each subquery you had originally)**

```
where
    u._id = @userId
```

Sorry for the useless formatting!

Note: the query engine is probably smart enough to use the same execution plan for both queries so you won't necessarily see an improvement

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to paste that query and highlight it in the
Query Editor, then clicking the Query Designer toolbar button? Management Studio will open the query within Query Designer, rewriting it in terms of joins.

Comment: yes i have tried but can't get sucess to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

an alternative would be to run all those count sub queries and store in seperate SP variables. Have you tried that to see if its more efficient than multiple sub queries in terms of caching etc?

Comment: no i think the best way of implementing it is by using joins only otherwise there is no use o PK FK relationship

Comment: Yep i definitely agree a single joined query is preferred, but I've not seen a query with joins + counts on each joined table as you need. I meant if you can't do it with joins you might try separate queries to store each count in a separate variable. I will favorite this because I'm interested in the solution also. Cheers